# Z-index on Home Page Navigation

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having trouble with the z-index setting on the home page of my site.  It is cutting off the longer sub-menus of drop downs.  It only does this on the home page.  The z-index is set to 9999.  This theme is called Scrollider from Woo Themes.  The sites url is www.kuhnflyfish.com.  I have tried adding a z-index property to many things in Chrome's developer tools.  If you scroll down just a little bit on the home page so that the content wrapper is just below the navigation, you can see the problem much easier.  I have even tried giving the content wrapper a negative z-index value, but that didnt work.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Below is the CSS from the them un-edited.

```
ul.nav ul {
  width: 11.089em;
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe the problem is the parent container `#content-top` is set to `z-index: 0;` and the `#wrapper` is set to `z-index: 2`.  Since the parent container is lower, the child element is also set lower.  You'll most likely have to place the navigation markup outside of the parent element, if you want it to overlap, then artificially set the z-index when the user scrolls so it covers up the nav at the correct point.

Comment: Simply stated, you cannot set children elements to higher z-index values than it's parents, and expect the children to overlap the parent's siblings.  You can see the explanation visually here: http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: Hey Axel, how does one go about moving the navigation markup outside the parent element?  Create a new div outside of #content-top and paste in navigation code in header.php?  Will that mess things up?

Comment: I actually think you can solve this without any markup changes.  I've posted an answer with my solution, which I've tested to be working in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove the `z-index` definitions from the parent containers, so that the children elements are on the same stacking context as the overlapping `#wrapper`.

To do this:

1. Remove `z-index` from `.has-slider #content-top` on **line 439** in **layout.css**
2. Remove `z-index` from `.has-slider #header` on **line 446** in **layout.css**
3. Add `z-index: -1;` to `.has-slider #featured-wrap` on **line 469** in **layout.css**

This will allow the `.sub-menu` elements to stack above the `#wrapper` container, since they are now both on the same stacking context.

Remember that setting the `z-index` on the parent will set a new stacking context.  Children within this parent cannot appear ABOVE any of the parent's siblings containing a higher `z-index` value then the initial parent.

---

A broken down explanation:

**Parent-1 (z-index: 1;)**
  -> Child (z-index: 999;) | Will appear below Parent-2, because Parent-1 has a lower z-index than Parent-2

**Parent-2 (z-index: 2;)**

Comment: Axel, thank you so much.  You are a z-index genius.  I got it to work in firefox, but so far haven't seen same result in Chrome for some reason.

Comment: It seems like Chrome creates a new stacking context when applying `position: fixed;` to an element.  This complicates things, because you want the nav menu to be in a fixed position, but also on the same stacking context as the wrapper (so you can set the dropdowns above it).  You'll have to rework your use of `position: fixed` to work with webkit browsers.  Here's an example of how it can work: http://codepen.io/wiltzius/pen/vhFzG

Comment: Thanks Axel.  Can your example be done just by playing with position in the css, or in my case will I need to edit the html as well?  I'm not real familiar rearranging html with a wordpress built site.

Comment: In your case, you would have to adjust the HTML as what you are trying to achieve will not work with the current markup in Chrome.

Comment: Hey Axel, sorry to write you back again.  I appreciate all the help you've given already.  I've been trying to follow your example in codepen, but I'm struggling to apply the model to my code.  Any other details to help this novice crack the code??  Frustrated I can't figure this out even with the help you've already given.  Thanks